# DateTime formate in php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have date stored in database in this format frankly i dont know the timezone of this format

> 2016-05-26T11:35:00.000Z

but i want to display date in this format

> May 27, 2016 12:00 am

Here is code

```
$date = substr($query_result->post_date, 0,10);
$date = date_create($date);
date_format($date,"F j, Y g:i a");
```

It shows date correctly but it always shows 12:00 am with date.
Like if date is

> 2016-05-26T11:35:00.000Z

then it should display

> May 26, 2016 11:35 am/pm

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `Z` at the end of that stored value is `Zulu` aka `UTC`, so that's your the timezone

Comment: It will only ever show 12:00am if you're taking just the date part in your `substr()` and discarding the time.... you're taking 10 characters from position 0.... that's `2016-05-26`

Comment: It works fine for me. `Echo date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime("2016-05-26T11:35:00.000Z"));`

Comment: @Andreas thnkx buddy it works fine....+1 for this

Answer (score 1):

While shrinking your datetime string, you lose time and timezone information. Time 00:00 and system timezone is then applied to your datetime, and you get wrong result because of that.

```php
$date = date_create($query_result->post_date);
date_format($date,"F j, Y g:i a");
```